# Bootstrap 5 - floating control for input group of button and datetime in razor pages

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, razor-pages

No bootstrap/css expert here. I'm trying to create a input for DateTime with corresponding arrows on sides using Bootstrap 5 and Razor Pages. My preliminary attempts left me with not satisfactory results.

I would like to have a ItemGroup consisting of DateTime pick and button on left with "arrow". Attempts created things like:
Example1:

```
<div class="input-group mb-3">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
   <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"><</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-floating">
   <input class="form-control" asp-for="startTime" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm}" />
   <label for="startTime">Start Time</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

resulting in

[image: example1]

It could be fine as long as button would have height of the form-floating div

or Example2:

```
<div class="form-floating">
  <div class="form-control" id="datetime_wrap">
   <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
     <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"><</button>
    </div>
    <input class="form-control" asp-for="startTime" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm}" />
   </div>
  </div>
  <label for="datetime_wrap">Start Time</label>
</div>
```

resulting in

[image: example2]

Second approach seems to be close to what I would like to achieve however bounding box of floating div should not cut thru the input box.

**Question**: is there's a way I can achieve this with vanilla bootstrap or I should drop a separate CSS class to fix such issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to read [the Bootstrap docs for input groups](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/input-group/)

You just didn't need the wrapping `.input-group-prepend` element.  Remove that and it works.  In fact the text "prepend" does not appear anywhere in the docs for the input groups, so I'm not sure where you got that from. Perhaps an older version of Bootstrap?

Also check out [the docs for floating labels](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/floating-labels/).
The order of the `<input>` and the `<label>` should be switched and a `placeholder` attribute is required so that it looks and works as expected with the animation

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container mt-3">

  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button">&lt;</button>
    <div class="form-floating">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startTime" asp-for="startTime" asp-format="{0:yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm}" placeholder="yyyy-MM-ddTHH">
      <label for="startTime">Start Time</label>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Indeed you're right. I have reviewed link I took example from and it was version 4. Thank you for your snippet, works as expected.